# Question closed as "broad" but there could have been a potentially useful answer

Tags: discussion

**Note:** This question is not about closed questions that already have an useful answer but more about questions which are closed as "broad" but could have had an answer which is useful to future readers.

Here is a sample scenario. A few days back one question was asked where the user wanted to know how to create a certain shape using CSS. However the question had no code and showed no indication of any attempt from the user's side. The question got closed as "broad" (no disputes, I agree with the closure). I had an answer on how to achieve that shape and had pinged the question's OP to show his efforts so that the question could be re-opened and the answer could be added. However, there was no response from the user and now the question is marked for deletion.

Now my question is, given that I feel an answer could be helpful for future readers, what is the appropriate course of action to add an answer?

1. Should I wait for some other user to post a similar question in future and then add the answer (or)
2. Should I edit the question and add some sample code to get the question re-opened and then add the answer (or)
3. Should I create a separate question, self answer it and leave it open for other interested users also to answer?

Personally, I don't think Option 2 sounds correct as it would set a wrong precedent.

I haven't posted a link to the actual question which I am referring to because this is not about a single instance.

Comment: In a [similar scenario](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210572/it-is-fun-to-have-fun-but-you-have-to-know-how-answer-the-question#comment675463_210573) (MSE) Oded suggested option 3.

Comment: @user000001: Thanks for the link mate. I felt the same too but wanted to check the opinion of the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I create a separate question, self answer it and leave it open for other interested users also to answer?

I assume you mean "leave my answer unaccepted". Otherwise, "leave it open" suggests that it would be a question that might require closure. This is the option that I think is most fruitful.

The more the OP of the original question *ignored* prompts to improve their question, the more justified this course of action is. **Their inaction regarding the question they posted indicates that they would not be a good custodian for the question.** Sure, everybody can edit a question but the OP is in a special position to get notifications upon comments on the question, new answers and edits that may be inappropriate so they are in a special position to take care of the question. Better have someone who can take care of the question than someone who can't. (Personal tragedy can incapacitate someone temporarily, which does not mean they would not in other circumstances be a good custodian, but I don't think it wise to *generally* hold off posting the new question *just in case* someone is experiencing personal tragedy.)

Comment: Thanks for the anwer mate. Yes, I meant leaving my answer unaccepted for a while so that others can chip in with alternates. I will wait a while to see if any alternate opinions to your answer comes up before marking it as accepted :)